# Google Maps - Adsense ads not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to display adsense ads on maps, but internet explorer gives me a hard time once again. The ads show on all other browsers I tried (chrome, ff, safari, opeara) but internet explorer. Has anyone encountered this before? here is my code for the admanager:

```
var publisherID = 'ca-pub-6630823543717184';

var adsManagerOptions = {
maxAdsOnMap : 1,
style: 'adunit',
channel: '5611474977'
};
adsManager = new GAdsManager(map, publisherID, adsManagerOptions);
adsManager.enable();
```

I am using xhtml1-strict doctype

Comment: Silly question, but I don't suppose you're running some sort of ad blocker on IE are you? Does adsense show up elsewhere?

Comment: oh no no :) all other ads are working, just not on maps; however ads on other websites using adsense on google maps work on my explorer, so something is wrong with my code. still trying to figure out though, as there is no error message either. bugger :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. You have to declare the script version as v=2.x whereas I had v=2

correct way:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&amp;sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I had

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&amp;sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this small ommission was causing IE not to display google ads on my maps. Problem solved!